# Word Wrap not working properly

Tags: css, wordpress, word-wrap

I'm trying to figure out why the word wrap is not working properly on this page for the div class:

```
.gce-page-list
```

http://metaphysicalerotica.com/events/

It looks like the theme has added a "pre" and "code" tag and if I delete the "pre" tag everything works fine, however I need a CSS fix to make the word-wrap work properly and I can't figure this out!  I have tried everything I can think of, any advice would be great!

Comment: Have you tried `word-wrap: break-word;` on that `DIV`'s CSS? I just tested it using Firebug and it shows the result you need.

Comment: pre, code, .gce-page-list, .gce-list, gce-feed-1 {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
}   still not getting the right result

Comment: I think that is because you are missing the `.` before `gce-feed-1`. And when you inspect your div it shows no class applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to your style sheet:

```
pre, code{ white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be for you to go in you style.css and add this class to line 67 for the "pre" and "code"

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

So the style would look like this...

```
pre, code {
   font-family: Courier New, monospace;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```