# Why is word-wrap not working?

Tags: html, css

My word-wrap is not working at all

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>very long word</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td style="word-wrap:break-word;">ablkasd/123123123/agsdfasdf/asdfasdfasdf/_sdfsdfsdf{123123-14werwwer-14124124-wefweshtsdf-235232323}/3235235/dasasdfasdfasdf.bsfs</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

The string is not breaking and is always in one line.

I already tried all solutions from [Word Wrap not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867804/word-wrap-not-working-properly)
but still not working

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You will need to add `table-layout: fixed;` to the table:

```css
table {width:100%; table-layout: fixed;}
table td {word-wrap:break-word;}
```

```html
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>very long word</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>ablkasd/123123123/agsdfasdf/asdfasdfasdf/_sdfsdfsdf{123123-14werwwer-14124124-wefweshtsdf-235232323}/3235235/dasasdfasdfasdf.bsfs</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Suggest please to use classes instead of inline-styles :)

Comment: @AlexChar I assume OP used it for simplicity. But you are right, it's cleaner to post CSS separately.

Answer (score 18):

Although the answer has been accepted, I would like to add to the accepted answer that apart from

```
table td {word-wrap:break-word;}
```

you need to ensure that the **white-space** property is not set to **nowrap** or **pre**.

This can prevent your td content word-wrapping even if you apply word-wrap: break-word

If some other css styles is setting you td white-space property, you can add

```
table td {
word-wrap:break-word;
white-space: normal;
}
```

This will ensure your td content has proper word-wrapping.

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: thanks for this answer. In my case white-space: normal was needed as you suggested.